# How to conditionally execute two different ExecStart commands in one systemd unit file?

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

I want to **conditionally execute either one of** (or both of) these commands in a **single** systemd unit file:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a 32
```

The first would execute on these conditions:

```
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

The second would execute on these conditions:

```
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
```

Both keys could be missing, or just one, or neither one. Obviously, if a key exists, I do not want to regenerate it. My question is in regard to ssh keys, but the concepts should be applicable to any systemd unit files. If there is a generic way to do this in unit files, it should work here (I assume).

The background is:

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service` includes:

```
Wants=sshdgenkeys.service
```

The standard contents of `/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshdgenkeys.service` are:

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH Key Generation
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

My problem with that unit file is **when any one key type is missing, all are re-generated**. I plan to remove dsa and ecdsa keys. So I only need to check two key types, and I only want to regenerate the specific keys that are missing, if any.

Please recommend how this can be accomplished. I have a related but different question here: [How to remove (not override, not create new) options from systemd unit files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572790/how-to-remove-not-override-not-create-new-options-from-systemd-unit-files). These two questions are independent and involve different aspects of working with unit files. This question is about conditionally executing different commands, the other question is about removing standard options from unit files.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions only apply to the whole unit, not to individual job specifications inside it.

So to conditionally execute some of the jobs, those job specifications should do the checking themself before performing the final action of them.

fe. like this: *(Not tested, just writing online)*

```bash
ExecStart=bash -c \
'\
  if test ! -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -o ! -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub; then\
    /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096;\
  fi\
' 'my-rsa-key-gen'
ExecStart=bash -c \
'\
  if test ! -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key -o ! -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub; then\
    /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a 32;\
  fi\
' 'my-ed25519-key-gen'
```

1. The `$$` is to prevent systemd from interpreting the `$` itself.\
From `man systemd.service` section "Command lines":

> To pass a literal dollar sign, use "$$".

2. The implicit `exit` commands are to return the status of `ssh-keygen` and prevent the unit from failing respectively.

*For best results, and ease, i would advise to create an external script to do all the conditional executions in one place.*

Comment: 1) `bash -r` disallows executing commands by path, so those blocks will fail if they have to do anything useful - why even use `-r` there? 2) There are no "implicit" exit commands there - they're all explicit. 3) Both `exit`s are pointless - `bash -c 'if test -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -o -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub; then ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096; fi'` will anyway return `0` if `test` failed, and the status of `ssh-keygen` if it had to execute `ssh-keygen`; 4) Shouldn't the condition be inverted?

Comment: As noted in the post "(Not tested, just writing online)", so i will fix the `-r`, the rest are just my habit of being explicit..WRT to your (4) Your're probably right when i rethink about his `ConditionPathExists=|!` lines...

Comment: Habit of being explicit or not, neither `exit` is _implicit_ as you say in the answer, and neither `exit` does anything to prevent the unit from failing.

Comment: Fine ill remove those also 